# selenium webdriver into jpanel

Tags: java

i am new in java i wonder if 
webbrowser selenium can run within a jpnel ?
or maybe add a botton to download files??

```
package Testing_Pack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class mytestclass {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in");
  String i = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  System.out.println(i);
 driver.close();
}
}
```